# Is "yuns" a word?

Tags: meaning, slang, north-american-english

I am asking if "yuns" is a word, and if it is, how do I use it?

Maybe it's just a north east american term, but I'm unsure how it's used in a sentence like:

> How **yuns** doing?

Comment: I assume you mean "you'uns.  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/you-uns

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/514484/different-words-for-the-personal-pronoun-you-in-spoken-ame-who-uses-which

Comment: FYI, In Pittsburgh, PA, U.S.A., we spell it, "Yinz." https://www.google.com/search?q=yinz

Comment: Short answer - if you're in the right place, just listen to the natives and imitate their usage. If you're not in the right place, you won't hear it, so don't use it.

Answer (score 4):

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/232195?redirectedFrom=yuns#eid)* says that *you-uns (yuns)* is U.S. regional and chiefly *Midland* and *Appalachian*, and adds that it can be used for both singular and plural *you*. It is formed within English by combining "you" *pron.* and the plural of "one" *pron.*

> **you-uns**, *pron.* 
> Second person singular or plural pronoun: = you *pron.*   Cf. you-all *pron.*

*OED* includes two sets of forms of the term:

> **Forms:** 
> α. 1800s **youns**, 1800s– **you'ns**, 1900s– **y'uns**, 1900s– **ye'ns**, 1900s– **yins** (*Pennsylvania*), 1900s– **yinz** (*Pennsylvania*), 1900s– **younz** (*Pennsylvania*), 1900s– **yunz** (*Pennsylvania*), 2000s– **y'uns**, 2000s– **yens**, 2000s– **yoons**, 2000s– **yuns**.
>
> β. 1800s **yo-uns**, 1800s **youans**, 1800s– **you 'ens**, 1800s– **you 'uns**, 1800s– **you ones**, 1800s– **you'uns**, 1800s– **you-uns**, 1900s– **you uns**, 1900s– **you-ones**, 1900s– **youin's**, 2000s– **you-ins**.

and adds this note:

> Since the second half of the 20th cent. the α. forms (especially *yinz, yunz*) have come to be considered as a defining characteristic of the speech of the inhabitants of Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania.

Funnily, the first written attestations of the two forms of the term *you-uns* are in citations talking about how people have heard about the term:

> α. 
> 1810     M. van H. Dwight Jrnl. 10 Nov. in *Journey to Ohio* (1912) 37     Youns is a word I have heard used several times, but what it means I don't know.
>
> β. 
> 1869     *Overland Monthly* Aug. 131/2     During the war we all heard enough of ‘we-uns’ and ‘you-uns’, but ‘you-alls’ was to me something fresh.

I'm also adding other citations from *OED* for you to see how it was used:

> <sub>α. 
>
> 1865   Atlantic Monthly Sept. 344/1   There 's a camp of our men out there, two hundred of them, and they will pay you'ns for pestering me! 
>
> 1921   Amer. Angler Sept. 259/1   We'll put y'uns up fer th' nite. 
>
> 1941   J. Agee & W. Evans Let us now praise Famous Men 371   I don't trust yuns. 
>
> 1981   S. McCool How to speak Pittsburghese at Yunz   Are yunz going to the game? 
>
> 1993   K. C. Constantine Bottom Liner Blues 117   Sure sure I did. I called plenty of times, but younz never come. Never. 
>
> 2006   Pittsburgh Post-Gaz. (Nexis) 24 Sept. h6   Yinz was drivin' pretty fast back there.</sub>

> <sub>β. 
>
> 1885   ‘C. E. Craddock’ Prophet Great Smoky Mountains 7   I hev no call ter spen' words 'bout sech ez that, with a free-spoken man like you-uns. 
>
> 1927   Amer. Speech 2 345   The paterfamilias questioned solicitously: Did you uns sleep good last night? 
>
> 1934   W. Faulkner Dr. Martino 341   Why did you uns have to stop here? 
>
> 1941   Amer. Mercury June 660/2   ‘Proud to know ye!’ Sam will beam. ‘Why, you-uns be a-comin' in ter th' fire an' set a spell.’ 
>
> 1996   J. Karon These High, Green Hills (1997) xi. 174   If they was anybody I'd do a favor, hit'd be you 'uns.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [The Review](https://www.reviewonline.com/opinion/local-columns/2021/12/yuns-should-be-proper-english/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CYuns%E2%80%9D%20is%20a%20contraction%20of,%27uns%20come%20over%20here.%E2%80%9D):

> “*Yuns*” is a contraction of two words: “you ones,” as in, “You’uns come over here.”

"*Yuns*" is plural, it should be used in the same context as "you ones".

The pronunciation of the words being like "Y’all, You’uns, Yinz, Youse" only exists in certain regional dialects; thus, they're not standard and proper words in the dictionary.

**Usage of "*yuns*" in a sentence:**

Instead of:

> How you ones doing? Long time no see!

You say:

> how ***yuns*** doing? Long time no see!

Comment: Please attribute your sources, links alone are insufficient. You can catch up on the guidelines  for attrubution by visiting EL&U meta.

Comment: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5196/44619

Comment: You have again failed to correctly reference material written by others. [Please review our Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and edit your post accordingly.